# MAXX referencing a measure - not always giving correct results

Tags: dax

I have a sales amount measure that looks as follows:

```
Sales Amount = 
        SUMX(
            'Online Sales',
            'Online Sales'[Sales Quantity] * 'Online Sales'[Unit Price] - 'Online Sales'[Discount Amount]
        )
```

When I create a Max Sales measure that references [Sales Amount], I don't always get the correct results when I'm several levels deep in a hierarchy.

Wrong Results:

```
Max Daily Sales = 
    MAXX(
        'Online Sales',
        [Sales Amount]
        )
    )
```

However, this does give the correct results:

```
Max Daily Sales = 
    MAXX(
        'Online Sales',
        SUMX(
            'Online Sales',
            'Online Sales'[Sales Quantity] * 'Online Sales'[Unit Price] - 'Online Sales'[Discount Amount]
        )
    )
```

They both appear to do the same thing. Does anyone know why the results would be different?

The data model looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: can you post an image of the data model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a measure within another measure, it's implicitly evaluated as if it is wrapped in a `CALCULATE`.

Allow me to quote from The Definitive Guide to DAX (Chapter 5 p. 114-115)

> Whenever you invoke a measure from inside another expression, DAX automatically encapsulates the measure inside *CALCULATE*.
>
> [...]
>
> Context transition happens automatically when calling a measure and there is no way to avoid it. This means that the only way to avoid context transition when calling a measure is to expand its code.

As I'm sure you recall, a context transition takes the row context and turns it into filter context for the measure. So when you call it as a measure, it's not summing over the same table but a filtered one based on the other values in that row.

Comment: This explains perfectly what is happening. It's the context transition that's causing the issue. The measure is being encapsulated inside a CALCULATE, and, since there is no filter on the CALCULATE, a context transition is occurring. Wow, DAX is simple until it's not.